# Validation Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, devise

Hi this is my User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :events

validates :cellphone, numericality:{ only_integer: true, message:"no es un numero"}, format: { with: /\d{11}/, message: "mal formato, deben ser 11 digitos, incluyendo codigo de area" }, :allow_blank => true
validates :phone, numericality:{ only_integer: true, message:"no es un numero"}, format: { with: /\d{11}/, message: "mal formato, deben ser 11 digitos, incluyendo codigo de area" }, :allow_blank => true
validates_numericality_of :cellphone, :on => :create, :message => "no es un numero", :allow_blank => true
validates_numericality_of :document, :on => :create, :message => "no es un numero", :allow_blank => true
validates :name, :presence => true
validates :lastname, :presence => true
validates :document, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
validates :cellphone, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
validates :phone, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true


validates_format_of :email,:with => Devise::email_regexp, :allow_blank => true

devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

I want to valida, example :cellphone, numericality only if it pass :cellphone, :presence => true validation.

I already read all the post here in StackOverflow but i cant seem to understand what they are doing.

If some1 could help me with this step by step.

Thanks

Comment: you allow blank and you validate presence and unicity. This is contradictory

Answer (score 0):

```
:allow_blank => true 
:presence => true
```

As @apneadiving mentioned in the comment, these two are 180 degree apart from each other. If one is true, the other one should be false. You can't have both at the same time.

What you are asking is that you want to check for the `numericality` if and only if the record is presence. For that, you can do the following:

```
 validates :cellphone, numericality:{ ... }, format: { ... }, :allow_blank => true
```

In this way, since `cellphone` field can be blank, `numericality` will only be checked for it if it exists.

The other option is: You can pass a block to check if the field exists, and it does, check for `numericality`.

Here's how:

```
 validate :cellphone, numbericality: { ... }, :if => lambda{ |object| object.cellphone.present? }
```

Comment: No, what im asking is the priority orden of validation, like if presence is true validate numericality, then if numbericality passes then validate format, but my projects validates all and show boths errors message

Comment: You can write a regular expression that can check both numericality and format at the same time. And that's what I do it. Why do you *only* want to check the format if numericality is true? Let format handle both the cases.

Comment: I want to check both of them but why show both error messages... its killing me, it shows "cellphone is not a number" "cellphone bad format" it show validate the format if it passes then check if its a number.